# sendAndConfirmTransaction odd behaviour

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

Its quite possible I have a logical error somewhere but I'll ask the question anyway as I am experiencing some very weird errors..

Is it possible for `web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(..` to return a signature but moments later (for that same invocation) to throw an exception even though my program has moved onto the next lines of code..

```
const createMintSig = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [this.appTreasPair, mintAccount], {
      skipPreflight: skipPreflight
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendAndConfirmTransaction` will always send the transaction, and then poll for the confirmation, so it's impossible for it to return and then fail.

You may have other code that executes during the `await` portion of the send and confirm transaction, which makes it look like it's moved on, or perhaps you're actually triggering it twice.

Here's the source code for it: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/24122768dada870de046743b89045364ecd7d4d5/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts#L18